# Node.js Facebook messenger chatbot - sender PSID is not defined

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, wit-ai

i developed a chatbot with nodejs and deployed it to heroku. but the webhook is not working properly since its gets an error saying **sender PSID is not defined**. what should I do? I need help from experts.. I haven't used wit.ai in my project but only node.js. and here i haven't posted post backs handlings as its too long!

my controllers.js as below.. (messages are in Sinhalese language)

```
       import dotenv from 'dotenv';
        dotenv.config();
        import request from 'request';
        
        
        const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
        const MY_VERIFY_TOKEN = process.env.MY_VERIFY_TOKEN;
        
        
        let test = (req, res) => {
            return res.send("hello again")
        
        }
        let getWebhook = (req, res) => {
        
            // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
            let VERIFY_TOKEN = MY_VERIFY_TOKEN
        
            // Parse the query params
            let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
            let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
            let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];
        
            // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
            if (mode && token) {
        
                // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
                if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
        
                    // Responds with the challenge token from the request
                    console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
                    res.status(200).send(challenge);
        
                } else {
                    // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
                    res.sendStatus(403);
                }
            }
        
        }
        
        let postWebhook = (req, res) => {
            let body = req.body;
            // Parse the request body from the POST
           
        
            // Check the webhook event is from a Page subscription
            if (body.object === 'page') {
        
                // Iterate over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
                body.entry.forEach(function (entry) {
        
                    // Gets the body of the webhook event
                    let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
                    console.log(webhook_event);
        
                    // Get the sender PSID
                    let sender_psid = webhook_event.sender.id;
                    console.log('Sender PSID: ' + sender_psid);
        
                });
                // Return a '200 OK' response to all events
                res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
        
            } else {
                // Return a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        
        }
        // Handles messages events
        function handleMessage(sender_psid, received_message) {
            let response;
            
            // Checks if the message contains text
            if (received_message.text) {    
              // Create the payload for a basic text message, which
              // will be added to the body of our request to the Send API
              response = {
                "text": `ආයුබෝවන්! ඔබ මේ සම්බන්ද වන්නේ chatbot IN සේවාව වෙතයි.!ඔබට මේ පිළිබද වැඩිදුර දැනගැනීමට අවශ්‍යද?`,
                "quick_replies":[
                    {
                      "content_type":"text",
                      "title":"Yes",
                      "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
                      
                    },{
                      "content_type":"text",
                      "title":"No",
                      "payload":"<POSTBACK_PAYLOAD>",
                      
                    }
                  ]
              } 
            } 
                       
            } 
            
            // Send the response message
            callSendAPI(sender_psid, response); 
    
    
    
// Sends response messages via the Send API
function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response) {
    // Construct the message body
    let request_body = {
      "recipient": {
        "id": sender_psid
      },
      "message": response
    }
  
    // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
    request({
      "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/me/messages",
      "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
      "method": "POST",
      "json": request_body
    }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('message sent!')
      } else {
        console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
      }
    }); 
  }




module.exports = {
 test: test,
 getWebhook: getWebhook,
 postWebhook: postWebhook

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First of all - which _type_ of webhook event are we talking about here?